# How to prevent users from editing/deleting cases' activity history records

Tags: security, salesforce

I'm preparing an org for a call center and the customer doesn't want the agents to be editing or deleting a cases' activity history records (for instance, if an email was sent, that record shouldn't be deleted from the history).

Is there a way to remove the edit/delete buttons on these records? Or is there a way that I can prevent these from being edited/deleted, maybe using a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Edit rights from the group that the agents belong to (remove "Manage Content Permissions"). This link may help:  https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/content_workspace_perm.htm

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the "Manage Content Permissions" option, only a "Settings" option there. Also, on which object should I remove edit rights from?

Comment: It sounds like they've updated their interface but not their documentation.  The group that the agents belong to should have their permissions changed, as then whenever agents come and go, you don't have to keep adjusting permissions.

Comment: Thanks James. By Group, do you refer to Profiles or Roles? Also, I can't find which one is the object I should change permissions for.

Comment: Profile- see this link for more help:  http://joshuaminton.com/blog/2011/7/21/system-permissions-and-data-access-rights-in-salesforcecom.html